# Ruby execute system command while running as service (systemd) on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, systemd

I want to run a ruby program as a service in Ubuntu but in my code I have a system call to execute an external program:

```
system(frame3dd, 'file.csv', 'file.out')
```

It works just fine when I run the program in terminal but as soon as I run it as a service, frame3dd returns error code 12. according to the manual it means:
12  : error in opening the temporary cleaned input data file for writing

```
Oct 09 10:56:57 vps594898 ruby[6900]:  FRAME3DD version: 20140514+
Oct 09 10:56:57 vps594898 ruby[6900]:  Analysis of 2D and 3D structural 
frames with elastic and geometric stiffness.
Oct 09 10:56:57 vps594898 ruby[6900]:  http://frame3dd.sf.net
Oct 09 10:56:57 vps594898 ruby[6900]:  GPL Copyright (C) 1992-2014, Henri P. 
Gavin
Oct 09 10:56:57 vps594898 ruby[6900]:  This is free software with absolutely 
no warranty.
Oct 09 10:56:57 vps594898 ruby[6900]:  For details, see the GPL license file, 
LICENSE.txt
Oct 09 10:56:57 vps594898 ruby[6900]: false
Oct 09 11:42:19 vps594898 ruby[14314]: #<Process::Status: pid 14415 exit 12>
```

systemd config file:

```
[Unit]
Description=BK Geveldragers staging

[Service]
User=server
Group=server
PIDFile=/home/server/bk_projecten/staging/server.pid
WorkingDirectory=/home/server/bk_projecten/staging
Restart=always

ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby server.rb
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: It could be a path or permission problem. Try calling [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#system-method) with `exception: true` to get an error.

Comment: I used a full path for frame3dd, I just shortened it here. I used the same user for running in systemd and in terminal.

Comment: If `false` in your log is the return value from `system`, it means that `frame3dd` terminated with a non-zero exit code (usually an error). Unfortunately it doesn't seem to print an error message. Maybe it's the input file path – have you tried passing the full / absolute path to `file.csv`?

Comment: Yes I just shortened the file path in here. In my program it's a full / absolute path.

Comment: Can you run `frame3dd` via `system` when you run the server manually?

Comment: Yes when running the server manually in terminal it works without problems. I changed system with Open3.capture3 to get the stderr output:  "\e[00;44;37;01m\e[00m\n\n\e[01m\e[41m\e[37m  \n  error: cannot open parsed input data file: '/tmp/frame3dd.3dd' \n  \e[00m\n\n"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Frame3dd creates temporary files in /tmp. Some of these files were created with root. When I was running Frame3dd with a non root account the program exits with error code 12 because it coudn't overwrite these files.

Comment: It's permission problems most of the time.